# What would be the result of the following code in big endian?

Tags: c++, windows, casting, endianness

Apparently it seems [Ideone](http://ideone.com) and [Codepad](http://codepad.org) both uses Little endian to compile and run their code.

If for example I want to test the following on Big endian CPU then I'm curious to know does casting the `unsigned char[]` array to `unsigned short*` really changes its output?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   unsigned char a[2] = {0, 1};
   unsigned short *s = (unsigned short*)a;
   std::cout << *s;
}
```

As far as I have known that if you cast an `int` to `char*` then it does depend on the endianness but what is case with arrays or any other type you try to reinterpret?

http://ideone.com/4UP0J0

Comment: This breaks the strict aliasing rule, isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Endian is a feature of the CPU, not the compiler...

Assuming your `short` type if 16 bits, and the unsigned chars are 8 bits then the memory layout of `a` will be

```
0x00 0x01
```

On a bit endian CPU this means that `*s` will be **1** (0x0001). On a little endian CPU `*s` will be 256 (0x0100).

As an aside, it's not so easy to find big endian CPUs any more. [This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instruction_set_architectures) has a list of CPU architectures from the last few decades and lists the endianness of each one.